# How can I prove that $\frac{\sin\theta+ \tan\theta}{2}> \theta$ when $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I don’t know how to do it without calculus, could someone help ? How do I prove it geometrically and/or algebraically ?

EDIT: $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$

My teacher never explained it. Someone tried explaining it to me with calculus, but I would appreciate a different explanation.

Comment: Do you have bounds on $\theta$, perhaps a specific interval to check?  Otherwise this inequality is false infinitely often...

Comment: Please state in your post what kind of methods you have tried so we know where you got stuck.

Comment: Sorry, $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Here's a graph of it if anyone wants: https://www.geogebra.org/classic/premqyks

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). This has a list of ways you can add context (supporting information) to your questions.

Comment: I’m not sure if there is a geometric way but thank you for your help. I will look at how to ask a good question for the future.

Comment: There is a geometric way: click the link called "Is there a geometrical method...". If you use Approach0, you will often find the answer to your question already there.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin \theta, \tan \theta > 0$ in the given domain, AM > HM so we have:

$$\frac{\sin\theta+ \tan\theta}{2} > \frac{2}{1/\sin \theta + 1/\tan \theta}$$

and $\csc \theta + \cot \theta = \cot(\theta/2)$, thus the RHS is $2 \tan(\theta/2) > 2 \cdot \theta/2 = \theta$.

In the last line, we have used the fact that $\tan x > x$ when $0 < x < \pi/2$.

Comment: You can get the identity for $\csc \theta + \cot \theta$ by finding $\cot^2(\theta/2) = \cos^2(\theta/2) / \sin^2(\theta/2) = \frac{1 + \cos \theta}{1 - \cos \theta}$. Now divide top and bottom by $\sin \theta$ and multiply by the conjugate. Using the result $\csc^2 x - \cot^2 x = 1$ gives the result.

Comment: thank you so much! This really helped